# Google Analytics not recognizing my second account when I try to "Verify your web tracking setup"

Tags: google-analytics

From the documentation [here](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1008083)

Can anyone see why this will not work? I assume tracking for UA-xxx-15 still works but I can't get Google Analytics to recognize that the code for UA-xxx-17 even exists...

```
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxx-15']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']);

  _gaq.push(['b._setAccount', 'UA-xxx-17']);
  _gaq.push(['b._setDomainName', 'example.com']);
  _gaq.push(['b._setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['b._trackPageview']);

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
```

Comment: I think you need to create multiple google analytics accounts and generate tracking code snippet separately. http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2456466&topic=1727147&ctx=topic

Comment: I've found several tutorials that do this the way I do it. I just can't figure out what might be different. http://www.jensbits.com/2012/03/28/tracking-multiple-domains-individually-and-as-a-group-in-google-analytics/
http://www.markinns.com/articles/full/adding_two_google_analytics_accounts_to_one_page
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891965/google-analytics-tracking-multiple-websites-top-level-domains

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code... How long have you waited for tracking data to show up? Sometimes with new profiles it may take as long as a day for data to show up in the reporting.

Comment: :/ It gives me the time it last checked: "Tracking Not Installed Last checked: Oct 27, 2012 1:17:06 PM PDT"

Comment: I'm curious as to how Google "detects" tracking code as it says. If it "detects" by matching text then obviously no, it won't be detected. But that seems too stupid a mistake for Google engineers to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer (that was no accepted) on this question to be the answer to my question as well.

It turns out Google Analytics will not recognize the tracking code unless you copy the exact code it gives you. This is very confusing, I think, because the tracking status can be either "Tracking Not Installed" or "Receiving Data" but when status is "Tracking Not Installed" it is also receiving data! The two status lines are the same, it seems, but the meaning of the latter is "You did not copy the exact code we gave you and put it on your website."